# SimpleMembershipProvider: Separate user profile tables for user and admin accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

I am using `WebMatrix.WebSecurity` in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

**The Problem:**

I need to separate regular user accounts and admin accounts in my application and I want to store them in two different tables like [**UserAccounts**] and [**AdminAccounts**]. Is that possible with the `SimpleMembershipProvider` and `WebSecurity` to have two different user profile tables?

For example, when I create a customer account, I want the [**UserAccounts**] table to be referenced from the [**webpages_Membership**] table, but when I am creating an admin account the [**AdminAccounts**] table should be referenced as a user profile table.

Actually I feel like I am on the wrong way. What is basically the best approach to separate customer and admin accounts?

Comment: This is typically handled using [Roles](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership)

Answer (score 0):

you can seperate two roles. Admin and User... SimpleMembership creates the UserInRoles table..

This is best approach to seperate customer and admin accounts.

you can control to users which account with the User.IsInRole() method as programaticly..

Answer (score 0):

I know about roles. My question was about having two different tables for customers and administrators with two different sets of columns and handle it with one `SimpleMembershipProvider`. My research on this topic showed this is not possible.